# Sensitive information in Android app?

Tags: android, keystore

I have a private keystore in my app, with a complex password. I also use a keyhash (in the keystore) for a webservice API.

Is it possible for attackers to extract the keyhash from the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* information available to your client (the app) is possible to extract, though some can be more difficult. As such, you should consider any such information public, and structure your security measures accordingly.

In your specific example, the complex password doesn't help much, since you will have to include the password in the code (or data) of your app. That means it can be extracted as well.

Comment: No i dont save password in myapp.my mean is keystore password

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but regardless: if your sensitive information is available to your app's code, it can be extracted.

Comment: I use private keystore in my app 

You know that exist keyhash and md5 and other in keystore

Comment: that keystore is used to link with the app version on playstore. Whenever you are going to update the playstore version application there you need to generate then latest apk using the same keystore and update app version and app code, otherwise you can't update the same application which exists at playstore. And about code security java itself is a secured language and the code wrapped inside apk is encrypted. If somebody tries to extract the code, it will generate data in some kind of coded characters.

Comment: So no one can get keystore information?

Comment: The keystore used to sign your app should be kept private. It is not possible to extract the keystore from the APK, unless you've *included* it into your app. But your question indicates that you've done so, if I understand it correctly (the part about a webservice API).  Additionally, Ankush Bist's statement about the code being encrypted is not true. The code is compiled into DEX bytecode, which is different from Java code, but certainly readable with the right tools.

Comment: I use keyhash in storekey in webservice.so if any one know that is keyhash then can use webservice.

Ok.Thanks

Comment: If you use it in a webservice, it must be included in your APK -- as such, it can be extracted. I will repeat myself: *any information accessible by your client is possible for the user to extract*.